# I want to numerically optimise a Runge Kutta problem

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I use the Runge Kutta method in Mathematica to solve a matrix differential equation, that depends on a number of variables. At the end of it, I extract some information that depends on my choice of variables at the start.

I want to be able to numerically optimise this such that the information I extract at the end is done with the best possible choice of variables. A fairly basic version of what I want to accomplish is written below

```
    opt[var_] := (
    cc1 =({{var/2, 1},{0, 1/(2 var)}});
    dd1 = ( {{0, t/var},{-var t, t}});

    rk={};
    it = 0; 
    steps = 10^4; 
    dt = 10/steps; 

    sf =cc1;

    lya[mat_, time_] := (dd1 /. t -> time).mat + mat.(dd1 /. t -> time)\[Transpose];

      Do[si = sf // N;
         k1 = lya[si, it] // N;
         k2 = lya[si + dt/2 k1, it + dt/2] // N;
         k3 = lya[si + dt/2 k2, it + dt/2] // N;
         k4 = lya[si + dt k3, it] // N;

       sf = si + \dt/6 (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4) // N;
      AppendTo[rk, {it, sf}];, {iterations, steps}];

     ee = var/2 sf[[1, 1]] + sf[[2, 2]]/(2 var)
    )
```

Let's say ee is what I want to optimise, and var is my variable. I assumed I could just call

```
    NMinimize[{opt[var],0<var<=5},var]
```

but the RungeKutta won't solve. I've looked around the Mathematica documentation for something around this, and came up with naught.

Any help is appreciated. More information available if required.

For context the actual code I'll be running has 6x6 matrices, with 10 variables to optimise over! these may be able to be reduced.

Thanks

Comment: Is a self implementation of RK4 necessary? Why not use e.g. `ParametricNDSolveValue` to solve the equation?

Comment: The code contains `\dt/6`, which is a syntax error  Also, `it` is initialized as `0` but never changes, even though it is used throughout the remainder of the code and saved in `rk`.  This, too, probably is an error.  Please correct.

Comment: dt in my original code is actually delta, thus the erroneous \ when I was editing the post. & youre correct, it is initialised as 0 and never changes in this code. This particular block was written solely for this post, as an example of what I need it to do. There should be an extra it = it+ dt inside the Do.

Comment: You can click the [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/138037/edit) button to correct the mistake in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `opt` with [`NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037),

```
opt[var_?NumericQ] := ...
```

to keep the function from being evaluated symbolically, which does not finish for a long, long time.
Your `opt` function works for me on numeric inputs, but your routine takes a long time:

```
opt[2.] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.52733, 1.06291} *)
```

That's just for one evaluation.  I didn't time this, but let it run over dinner:

```
FindMinimum[{opt[var], 0 < var <= 5}, {var, 2.}]
(* {0.501664, {var -> 1.00167}} *)
```

`NMinimize[]` would work, too, but will take much longer, most likely, given that it tends to evaluate the objective function more times.

Comment: The ?NumericQ was a good shout! Thank you very much